# Subscriptions "Pending payment" - Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, payment, subscription, trial

I have an app that I've implemented subscriptions. This subscription is bases on 3 days free trial, and then it charges the corresponding amount that is set. I've configured 3 days as a grace period. The problem is that all the subscriptions that not canceled after trial period are in "**Pending payment**" status.

I do not believe that 100% of the subscriptions are pending payment and none have been charged.

In the following screenshot you can check two of many example, as you see the status is "Pending payment".

[image]

This is the detail of one of the "pending payment" subscriptions

[image: This is the detail of one of the "pending payment" subscriptions]

Does anyone have this problem and knows of a way to solve this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem also regularly occurs to me and in the past I have contacted Google about it. They replied saying that the issue is that the money is not reaching them, and that is why it says "Payment Pending". This means that it is an issue with the users payment reaching Google.

From this it seems that there is nothing we can do to fix this except from increasing Grace Period and wait that hopefully the money will arrive.

Comment: Is it due to a trial period in the subscription? If you remove trial period will it work normally?

Comment: No, trials are listed separately with the value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of situation happens when the payment is not fully completed. You should check if the field "status" is Active or Cancelled. Only "Active" subscriptions are valid ones.

Regards.